# Existence of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

$ \lim_{x \to x_0^-}  f(x) $ exists and is finite  $\iff $  $ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $ x_0 - \delta < x_1, x_2 < x_0 \implies |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | < \epsilon $

I believe I have proven the forward direction using an $ \frac{\epsilon}{2} $ argument. For the backwards direction, I think I need to show that the left limit superior and left limit inferior are equal, but I'm not sure how to go about showing that $f$ is bounded first.

Comment: Is this for a particular function $f \left( x \right)$, or just for any function in general?

Comment: This is for any function in general.